# program stopped working in android Emulator

Tags: android, eclipse

I have written the program of calculator for android in Eclipse and no error was appeared while I was completing the codes but when the Emulator is running and for example entering two numbers to sum when the equation operator has clicked,this error appear "unfortunately app has stopped"

my Main.java

```js
package com.Tools.s01_e07;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class Main extends Activity {

 private TextView show;
 private ImageView n1;
 private ImageView n2;
 private ImageView n3;
 private ImageView n4;
 private ImageView n5;
 private ImageView n6;
 private ImageView n7;
 private ImageView n8;
 private ImageView n9;
 private ImageView n0;
 
 private ImageView nf1;
 private ImageView nf2;
 private ImageView nf3;
 private ImageView nf4;
 private ImageView nf5;
 private ImageView nf6;
 
 private int V1;
 private String F;
 private int V2;
 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        
        n1=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.n1);
        n2=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.n2);
        n3=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.n3);
        n4=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.n4);
        n5=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.n5);
        n6=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.n6);
        n7=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.n7);
        n8=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.n8);
        n9=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.n9);
        n0=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.n0);
        
        nf1=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nf1);
        nf2=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nf2);
        nf3=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nf3);
        nf4=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nf4);
        nf5=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nf5);
        nf6=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nf6);
        show=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.show);
        
        n1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
       
    show.setText(show.getText()+"1");
   }
  });
        
        n2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
  
    show.setText(show.getText()+"2");
   }
  });
        
        n3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
  
    show.setText(show.getText()+"3");
   }
  });
        
        n4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
  
    show.setText(show.getText()+"4");
   }
  });
        
        n5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
  
    show.setText(show.getText()+"5");
   }
  });
        
        n6.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
  
    show.setText(show.getText()+"6");
   }
  });
        
        n7.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
  
    show.setText(show.getText()+"7");
   }
  });
        
        n8.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
  
    show.setText(show.getText()+"8");
   }
  });
        
        n9.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
  
    show.setText(show.getText()+"9");
   }
  });
        
        n0.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
  
    show.setText(show.getText()+"0");
   }
  });
        
        nf1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
  
    V1=Integer.parseInt(show.getText().toString());
    F="+";
    show.setText(" ");
   }
  });
        
        nf2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    V1=Integer.parseInt(show.getText().toString());
    F="-";
    show.setText(" ");
    
   }
  });
        
        nf3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
  
    V1=Integer.parseInt(show.getText().toString());
    F="*";
    show.setText(" ");
   }
  });
        
        nf4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
  
    V1=Integer.parseInt(show.getText().toString());
    F="/";
    show.setText(" ");
   }
  });
        
        nf5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
  
    if(F!=""  && show.getText().toString()!="")
       {
    int res=0;
    V2=Integer.parseInt(show.getText().toString());
    if(F=="+"){
      
     res=V1+V2;
    }
               if(F=="-"){
     
                res=V1-V2;
    }
               if(F=="*"){
     
                res=V1*V2;
    }
               if(F=="/"){
                
                res=V1/V2;
     
    }
       
               show.setText(res+"");
        } 
   }
  });
        
        nf6.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
  
   }
  });
        
    }


   
    
}
```

main.xml

```js
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.Tools.s01_e07.Main" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/n1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="116dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
        android:src="@drawable/a01" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/n2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/n1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/n1"
        android:src="@drawable/a02" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/n3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/n2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/n2"
        android:src="@drawable/a03" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/n4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/n1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/n1"
        android:src="@drawable/a04" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/n5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/n1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/n1"
        android:src="@drawable/a05" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/n6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/n3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/n5"
        android:src="@drawable/a06" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/n7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/n4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/n4"
        android:src="@drawable/a07" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/n8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/n7"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/n7"
        android:src="@drawable/a08" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/n9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/n6"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/n8"
        android:src="@drawable/a09" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/n0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/n2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/n1"
        android:src="@drawable/a00" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/nf5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/n2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/n2"
        android:src="@drawable/mosavi" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/nf1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/n9"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/n9"
        android:src="@drawable/sum" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/nf2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nf1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nf1"
        android:src="@drawable/tafrigh" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/nf3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nf2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/n3"
        android:src="@drawable/zarb" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/nf4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/nf3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nf3"
        android:src="@drawable/taghsim" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/nf6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/n1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/nf4"
        android:src="@drawable/p2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/show"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/n7"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/n7"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/nf1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my LogCat

```js
03-20 14:59:37.211: D/dalvikvm(1225): GC_CONCURRENT freed 69K, 5% free 6286K/6616K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 26ms
03-20 14:59:37.283: D/libEGL(1225): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
03-20 14:59:37.287: D/(1225): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb78f8410, tid 1225
03-20 14:59:37.299: D/libEGL(1225): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
03-20 14:59:37.299: D/libEGL(1225): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
03-20 14:59:37.355: W/EGL_genymotion(1225): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-20 14:59:37.367: D/OpenGLRenderer(1225): Enabling debug mode 0
03-20 15:00:01.239: D/AndroidRuntime(1225): Shutting down VM
03-20 15:00:01.239: W/dalvikvm(1225): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa613f908)
03-20 15:00:01.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1225): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 15:00:01.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1225): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: " 2"
03-20 15:00:01.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):  at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
03-20 15:00:01.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):  at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
03-20 15:00:01.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
03-20 15:00:01.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
03-20 15:00:01.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):  at com.Tools.s01_e07.Main$15.onClick(Main.java:173)
03-20 15:00:01.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
03-20 15:00:01.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
03-20 15:00:01.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-20 15:00:01.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-20 15:00:01.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-20 15:00:01.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-20 15:00:01.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 15:00:01.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-20 15:00:01.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-20 15:00:01.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-20 15:00:01.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post your stacktrace from LogCat please, we are not magicians.

Comment: Try to find best practices for calcs, cause this one is really bad. For simple calcs - you need to use two variables, and perform selected operation. For complex calcs it is better to use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation, for advance calcs it is better to use ready-to-use libs

Comment: thanks I use two variable V1 & V2 ,when we click on operator  , first number stand in V1 and cleaned TextView.when click on equation operator second number stand in V2

Answer (score 1):

When an operator button is pressed, you set the show TextView to " " (space) and then append the digits of the second operator to it.
You probably get a NumberFormatException in parseInt.
You should also not trust the user clicking the buttons as they normally should.